# Modify MethodCallExpression arguments (C# LINQ)

Tags: linq, nhibernate, odata

I need to add arguments to a `MethodCallExpression` before it is executed for a GET request

This is the OData GET request to load all employees:

```
server/employees?$filter=birthday+ge+datetime'1985-01-01'
```

I have tried with following code:

```
// My class inherits from IQToolkit which is building an expression based on the request
public class MyQueryProvider : QueryProvider 
{
    // Is defined in advance (after a client established a connection)
    private int clientDepartmentNo;

    // This is the central function, which gets a MethodCallExpression from the toolkit 
    // and executes it
    public override object Execute(MethodCallExpression expression)
    {
        // The current content of expression (see my OData URL above):
        // "value(NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Models.Employee]).Where(it => (it.Birthday >= Convert(01.01.1985 00:00:00)))"

        // Now I would like to extend the expression like that:
        // "value(NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Models.Employee]).Where(it => (it.Birthday >= Convert(01.01.1985 00:00:00)) && it.DepartmentNo == clientDepartmentNo)"

        // That works fine
        var additionalExpressionArgument = (Expression<Func<Employee, bool>>)(x => x.DepartmentNo == clientDepartmentNo);


        // But that is still not possible, because the property .Arguments is readonly...
        expression.Arguments.Add(additionalExpressionArgument);
        // Can you give me an advice for a working solution?


        // Would like to execute the query based on the URL and extension
        return nHibernateQueryProvider.Execute(expression);
    }
}
```

What should I do in place of the `expression.Arguments.Add` above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing your `QueryProvider` is the one from [here](https://github.com/mattwar/iqtoolkit), and that hard-coding the queried entity as in your question is suitable for you, it should be simple:

```
public override object Execute(MethodCallExpression expression)
{
    var query = (Query<Employee>)(CreateQuery<Employee>(expression)
        .Where(x => x.DepartmentNo == clientDepartmentNo));

    return nHibernateQueryProvider.Execute(query.Expression);
}
```

But there are probably better means to do that, since that toolkit is here for building expression. Having to hard cast as I do above looks like a code smell.